# how to capture the 1st command output in terminal and to print that variable using the last command in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep

actual output comes as

```
$ grep -Hcw count copy_hb_script 
copy_hb_script:5
```

I'm using the below command to get the expected out put but I'm failing

```
grep -Hcw count copy_hb_script | awk '{print $1}' |xargs ls -ld | awk '{print $8 " " $9 }'
```

getting out put is

```
03:49 copy_hb_script
```

Missing the count of the file, is there any alternate to get the time stamp with count of the file like below

```
03:49 copy_hb_script:5
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve], otherwise this is not very clear

Comment: This looks like someone that is cludging together commands they've found on the internet, w/o learning what the commands to.  e.g. you use `grep -Hcw` and then you (try to) strip off the -H part.  Just don't use -H.  You are using xargs, yet you are returning one file name.  Learn each command you are using in your pipes.

Comment: @ SaintHax: pls check @lnian answer to know what I'm looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [`can avoid parsing ls output`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and use the `stat` command in bash for detailed file information.

```
 #  'stat -c' produces output as 2016-09-15 16:03:40.655456000 +0530
 #   Stripping off extra information after the '.' using string-manipulation            
 #   Running the grep with the count together with the previous command

 modDate=$(stat -c %y copy_hb_script); echo "${modDate%.*}" "$(grep -Hcw count copy_hb_script)"
```

Produces an output as

```
016-09-15 16:03:40 copy_hb_script:5
```